# Control Multiple Stepper Motors with Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I am building a refreshable braille display using a Pi 3 B+ and a Stepper Motor System.

The system works by rotating an octagonal disc each on 2 different stepper motor to display the appropriate braille lettering (each side on the octagonal disc has a different letter). I want to have multiple sets (at least 2) of this display system (the display system itself requires 2 stepper motors).** Is there any way to control 4+ (or at least 2+) stepper motors to work simulatenously but also independently using the Pi. **

I've done some research and I am wanting to use a unipolar stepper motor (something like this: https://www.amazon.ca/SazkJere-ULN2003-Stepper-28BYJ-48-Compatible/dp/B0BVVMF8DS/ref=sr_1_12?keywords=stepper+motor&qid=1704415148&sr=8-12). But, I don't know how one could wire the ULN2003 control board for the motor with the Pi, and even if I could, it looks like there aren't enough GPiO pins on the Pi to support more than 2 motors.

**If anyone has any ideas, please let me know!**

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question, but the most difficult part of driving stepper motors is accurately generating the pulses that control when the stepper motors switch to the next step.  The Raspberry Pi itself probably won't be good for this because it's running Linux.  Check out https://www.pololu.com/category/212/tic-stepper-motor-controllers

Comment: I believe you need 4 digital outputs to control one stepper motor. They do not have to be PWM outputs. Since RPi has more than 20 GPIO, you should be able to control more than 4 motors. You might also consider using Arduinos in this application, as they are inexpensive and you could right a simple program that rotates each motor to the right location using a serial port command.

Comment: With a typical stepper motor driver (e.g A4990), you just need two outputs: DIR and STEP.  Accurately generating pulses on the STEP pin at the right time is the tricky part, like I said.

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/stepper-motor-basics/275223
Best intro I found out there.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of trouble to have RPi (with Python) to drive more than one motor without killing the pace/frequency/PPS.
ended up with a library, currently with implementations for DRV8825 or equivalent hardware, a specific motor I'm working with and GenericMotor that you can pass maxPPS at build time.
ideally it could run up to 13 steppers, with 2 pins per stepper (either in full step mode or wiring stepping mode pins from drivers to some other hardware driven signal, else you need 5 pins per driver).

I was adding final touches to the README so if you find something hard to follow I'm happy to hear about it.

Hope it helps, I tested with two motors and love the results. (have to use the multiprocess factory class to work with multiple motors so a dedicated python process handles is without your app stealing CPU ticks).

https://github.com/juanmf/StepperMotors/

Comment: DRV8825 is Bipolar, I can help implementing unipolar if needed and current implementation cant'd handle it. as long as the driver is happy receiving short pulses at a given PPS rate.